# Social Login. Social Authentication? Searching for a framework

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, opensocial, authentication

I'm trying to find a framework for user login that is the following:

- Easy to implement / maintain.
- Easy to use a simple if statement to test if the user is logged in
- User stays logged in from page to page and framework handles all that
- Has social login abilities for at least Facebook, but also Twitter, Wordpress, etc.
- Easy to integrate with MySQL and I can add extra "profile" fields without having to deal with framework.

Pluses
 - Has social login for tumblr?
 - Easy share buttons, etc.

I've already discovered Gigya, [LoginRadius](https://www.loginradius.com/), [OneAll](http://www.oneall.com/), and Janrain. The problem is that they have terrible documentation and I'm really not sure if I'm supposed to integrate them into my own authentication/sessions system or if it's supposed to take care of that for me.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

Try http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/
Its easy to use and has a ton of providers with only one .php fle

Answer (score 0):

try facebook login if required
http://www.sourceaddons.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing similar research myself recently and to be honest there is no single perfect framework that handles all of that. The best you can get is [CakePHP Facebook plugin](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin) which covers all aspects related with Facebook and [Opauth](http://opauth.org/) as mentioned above with [Google+, Tumblr and other strategies](https://github.com/opauth/opauth/wiki/List-of-strategies). You may also try [hybridauth](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth) but anyways integrating opauth and hybrid auth comes with code you have to write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

FuelPHP's Auth module has full Opauth integration, without any need for external solutions.

Answer (score -1):

What is Opauth? http://opauth.org/

Inspired by OmniAuth for Ruby, Opauth provides a standardized method for PHP applications to interface with authentication providers.

Opauth as a framework provides a set of API that allows developers to create strategies that work in a predictable manner across PHP frameworks and applications.

Opauth works well with other PHP applications & frameworks. It is currently supported on:

vanilla (plain) PHP applications (of course)
CakePHP (maintained by uzyn)
CodeIgniter (maintained by destinomultimedia)
CodeIgniter (maintained by mcatm)
FuelPHP (maintained by andreoav)
Laravel (maintained by FakeHeal)
PrestaShop (maintained by Onasusweb)
Silex (maintained by icehero)
Yii Framework (maintained by kahwee)
Zend Framework 2 (maintained by lorenzoferrarajr)
Nette (maintained by michalsvec)
and more to come.
If your PHP framework of choice is not yet listed, you can still use Opauth like you would a normal PHP component (class).